# Tailwind styles are not being applied after bundling with Rollup

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, rollupjs, postcss, rollup-plugin-postcss

Apologies if this is an obvious question, this is my first time trying to build a component library.

I'm building a React component library with Tailwind CSS 3. When I run the components with Storybook, they display as intended. However, when I bundle with Rollup, the class names are applied, but the CSS is not included in the build.

This is my `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

My `rollup.config.js` file:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.js',
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        minimize: true,
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top',
        },
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
      }),
      external(),
      resolve(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
];
```

My `postcss.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

And my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "@jro31/react-component-library",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "A library of React components",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jro31/react-component-library.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "components",
    "component-library",
    "react-component-library"
  ],
  "author": "Jethro Williams",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jro31/react-component-library/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jro31/react-component-library#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.75.7",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/jro31"
  }
}
```

My `src/index.css` file is simply:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I only have one dummy component for now. Based on this, when I run `npm run storybook`, my component displays as intended with the Tailwind styling applied.

However, on running `npm run rollup`, the `dist/esm/index.js` file is generated as follows:

```js
import t from"react";const e=e=>t.createElement("button",{className:"text-9xl md:text-6xl bg-blue-400"},e.label);export{e as Button};
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

It includes the Tailwind classnames, but not styling. So importing this component into an external project, the class names are applied, but the Tailwind styling is not.

Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? I've spent a few hours trying to fix this, so would be incredible grateful for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I needed to import my `src/index.css` file *into* my component.

My `src/index.css` file is simply:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then in my `src/components/index.js` file I imported this file:

```js
import '../index.css';

export { default as Button } from './Button';
```

Now the styling gets included in the Rollup bundle.

After all I tried, I can't believe it was this simple. I hope at least that this answer helps someone else avoid going through the same pain and suffering.

Answer (score 2):

Given your rollup.config.js:

```
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.js',
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        minimize: true,
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top',
        },
      }),
```

You should be able to change it to this:

```
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';

const tailwindConfig = require('./tailwind.config.js');

...

    plugins: [
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.js',
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        minimize: true,
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top',
        },
        plugins: [tailwindcss(tailwindConfig)],
      }),
```

That should allow you to have package.json scripts as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "rollup -c --watch",
    "build": "rollup -c"
},
```

Beyond that the accepted answer is what you need. I typically import the css file into the entry point of the application or npm library (root `index.js` file that is bundled with rollup), shown here in your rollup.config.js file:

```
export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.js',
```